# Node - "Unable to deserialize cloned data" when serializing multiple values

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, ecmascript-6, v8

I want to implement a custom serializer for my class so I can use it for networking. However, `d.readValue` throws an error: "Unable to deserialize cloned data."

```
Error: Unable to deserialize cloned data.
    at /home/runner/QuarrelsomeBurdensomeClick/index.js:7:15
```

```js
const { Serializer, Deserializer } = require("v8");

let s = new Serializer();
s.writeValue("Abc");
s.writeValue("Def");
let d = new Deserializer(s.releaseBuffer());
console.log(d.readValue()); // Error here.
console.log(d.readValue());
```

Oddly, if one of the `writeValue` calls is removed along with a `readValue`, the code is run as expected.

How do I serialize multiple values without this error?